# Maximum recursion depth exceed with combo of ax.set_xlim() and ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed')

Tags: matplotlib, callback

I've written a piece of code that displays different regions  of the same plot (i.e. plotted in different axes), so when you pan/zoom in one of the axes using the NavigationToolbar, it adjusts the others based on a predefined function.

Rather than having this for two axes, I wanted to generalize the class to take any number of axes. However when I make the modifications (see code below), it results in a 'Maximum recursion depth exceed' error upon using ax.set_xlim(), even when I'm using the exact same two axes. The previous version of the code which had hardcoded the two different axes all the attributes and functions worked, so I'm confused how this happens. I'm assuming matplotlib is freaking out with the multiple events being made, but it's not clear to me how to stop this from happening that works in the hardcoded version.

Generalized code:

```
class OffsetAxes():
    def __init__(self, axs):
        self.axs=axs
        self.offsetaxes(axs[0],0)
        return
    def connect(self):
        self.cids=[]
        for ax in self.axs:
            self.cids.append(ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed',self.on_change_lims))
        return
    def disconnect(self):
        for ii,ax in enumerate(self.axs):
            self.ax.callbacks.disconnect(self.cids[ii])
        return

    def offsetaxes(self,currentax,axind):
        self.disconnect()
        for ii,ax in enumerate(self.axs):
            if ii!=axind:
                newxlim=GetModifiedLimits()#Function that shift x-limits
                ax.set_xlim(newxlim)#ERROR OCCURS HERE
        self.connect()
        return

    def on_change_lims(self,currentax):
        jj=0
        for ii,ax in enumerate(self.axs):
            if ax==currentax:
                jj=ii
        self.offsetaxes(currentax,jj)
        return
```

Hard-coded version:

```
def __init__(self, ax1, ax2):
    self.ax1=ax1
    self.ax2=ax2
    self.offsetaxes(self.ax1, self.ax2)
    return
def connect(self):
    self.cidAx1 = self.ax1.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', self.on_change_lims)
    self.cidAx2 = self.ax2.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', self.on_change_lims)
def disconnect(self):
    self.ax1.callbacks.disconnect(self.cidAx1)
    self.ax2.callbacks.disconnect(self.cidAx2)
    return

def offsetaxes(self, axes_to_keep, axes_to_change):
    self.disconnect()
    newxlim=GetModifiedLimits()#Function that shift x-limits
    axes_to_change.set_xlim(newxlim)

    self.connect()
    return

def on_change_lims(self, axes):
    if axes == self.ax2:
        self.offsetaxes(self.ax2, self.ax1)
    elif axes == self.ax1:
        self.offsetaxes(self.ax1, self.ax2)
    return
```